# ArrayIndexOufOfBoundsException

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Hello I wanted to create a multiple quiz app, but when the app is at the last question, it stops suddenly. I want it to show a dialog where it counts the final score, then go back to main.

This is the error

```
12-07 22:38:17.997 29516-29516/com.example.ancaalexandra.proiectandroidd E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                               Process: com.example.ancaalexandra.proiectandroidd, PID: 29516
                                                                                               java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
                                                                                                   at com.example.ancaalexandra.proiectandroidd.QuestionsBD.getQuestion(QuestionsBD.java:27)
                                                                                                   at com.example.ancaalexandra.proiectandroidd.BazeDeDate1Activity.updateQuestion(BazeDeDate1Activity.java:150)
                                                                                                   at com.example.ancaalexandra.proiectandroidd.BazeDeDate1Activity.access$400(BazeDeDate1Activity.java:19)
                                                                                                   at com.example.ancaalexandra.proiectandroidd.BazeDeDate1Activity$1.onClick(BazeDeDate1Activity.java:78)
                                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261)
                                                                                                   at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11185)
                                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23752)
                                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

This is QuestionsBD class, where i create the questions and their answers:

```
class QuestionsBD {

private String bdquestions[]= {
        "Componenta de date dintr-un SBD poate contine: ",
        "In arhitectura unui SBD pe niveluri, viziunea programatorului corespunde: ",
        "Arhitectura pe componente a unui sistem de  baze de date contine:"};

private String bdChoices[][]={
        {"Sistemul de operare","Sistemul de coduri","Dictionarul distribuit","Fisierele anexe"},
        {"Nivelul fizic","Nivelul SO","Nivelul logic","Nivelul SGBD"},
        {"Datele","Fisierele","Software-ul de comunicatie","Programe de comunicatie"}
};

private String bdCorrectAns[]={"Fisierele anexe", "Nivelul logic","Datele"};


public String getQuestion(int a)
{
    String question= bdquestions[a];
    return question;
}

public String getChoice0(int a)
{
    String choice0=bdChoices[a][0];
    return choice0;
}

public String getChoice1(int a)
{
    String choice1=bdChoices[a][1];
    return choice1;
}

public String getChoice2(int a)
{
    String choice2=bdChoices[a][2];
    return choice2;
}

public String getChoice3(int a)
{
    String choice3=bdChoices[a][3];
    return choice3;
}



public String getCorrectAnswer(int a)
{
    String answer=bdCorrectAns[a];
    return answer;
}

public int getNrQuestions()
{
    int nrquestions=bdquestions.length;
    return nrquestions;
    }
}
```

And this is the activity where are shown the questions:

```
public class BazeDeDate1Activity  extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private QuestionsBD questBd = new QuestionsBD();

    private TextView scoreTW;
    private TextView questionsTW;
    private Button choice0;
    private Button choice1;
    private Button choice2;
    private Button choice3;
    private Button choiceQuit;
    private ImageView numberPhoto;

    private String answer;
    private int scoreInit = 0;
    private int questionNumber = 0;
    private String quit = "quit";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_baze_de_date1);

        View v = findViewById(R.id.buttonBD1quit);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);

        /*AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Scor final: " + scoreInit);
        builder.setTitle("Felicitari!!");

        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int idok) {

            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
*/
        scoreTW = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewScorObtinut);
        questionsTW = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewIntrebare1BD);
        choice0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBD1r1);
        choice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBD1r2);
        choice2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBD1r3);
        choice3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBD1r4);
        choiceQuit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBD1quit);
        numberPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewONE);

        //updateQuestion();

        choice0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (choice0.getText() == answer) {
                    scoreInit = scoreInit + 1;
                    updateScore(scoreInit);
                    Toast.makeText(BazeDeDate1Activity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    updateQuestion();


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(BazeDeDate1Activity.this, "Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        updateQuestion();


                }
            }
        });

        choice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (choice1.getText() == answer) {
                    scoreInit = scoreInit + 1;
                    updateScore(scoreInit);
                    Toast.makeText(BazeDeDate1Activity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        updateQuestion();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(BazeDeDate1Activity.this, "Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    updateQuestion();
                }

            }
        });

        choice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (choice2.getText() == answer) {
                    scoreInit = scoreInit + 1;
                    updateScore(scoreInit);
                    Toast.makeText(BazeDeDate1Activity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(BazeDeDate1Activity.this, "Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        });

        choice3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (choice3.getText() == answer) {
                    scoreInit = scoreInit + 1;
                    updateScore(scoreInit);
                    Toast.makeText(BazeDeDate1Activity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(BazeDeDate1Activity.this, "Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        });


    }



    private void updateQuestion()
    {
        questionsTW.setText(questBd.getQuestion(questionNumber));
        choice0.setText(questBd.getChoice0(questionNumber));
        choice1.setText(questBd.getChoice1(questionNumber));
        choice2.setText(questBd.getChoice2(questionNumber));

        answer=questBd.getCorrectAnswer(questionNumber);
        questionNumber++;
    }

    private void updateScore(int point)
    {
        scoreTW.setText(""+scoreInit);
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.buttonBD1quit)
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,BeginActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3` Please explain what research you did on this error and what exactly is confusing you about it.

Answer (score 0):

When you finish the last question, the code still runs trying to update to a 4th question, or index 3 in the bdquestions[] array.  You need to add a check to make sure it stops after the last question, something like this:

```
private void updateQuestion()
{
    if (questionNumber < questBd.getNrQuestions()) {
        questionsTW.setText(questBd.getQuestion(questionNumber));
        choice0.setText(questBd.getChoice0(questionNumber));
        choice1.setText(questBd.getChoice1(questionNumber));
        choice2.setText(questBd.getChoice2(questionNumber));

        answer=questBd.getCorrectAnswer(questionNumber);
        questionNumber++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `String getQuestion(int a)` with a value of 3 when 3 is the hardcoded size of the `bdquestions` array. There are multiple ways this could be solved but the fundamental issue is your application design, using hardcoded datasets and a codebase that has an expectation of the hardcoded data being there. You can check if the number is < 3 but that will just hide the problem instead of fixing it.

For starters, you should have a data type for your questions/answers:

```
public class Question {

    public Question(String question, int answerIndex, String... answers) {
        this.question = question;
        this.correctAnswerIndex = answerIndex;
        this.answers.addAll(Arrays.asList(answers));
    }

    private String question;

    private List<String> answers = new ArrayList<>();

    private int correctAnswerIndex = 0;

    private String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    private List<String> getAnswers() {
        return answers;
    }

    private String getCorrectAnswer() {
        if(answers.size() > correctAnswerIndex) {
            return answers.get(correctAnswerIndex);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

From there, you can access it directly (and safely) by iterating through the possible answers with a for loop, getting the answer in a non-hardcoded fashion, and so forth. The biggest part of making an application that is protected against crashes or undefined behavior is designing it carefully so that error states are difficult to create.